# Error: Near Initialization for typedef struct array

Tags: struct, initialization, typedef

Compiler returns ***(near initialization for 'test_value[2].unit') [enabled by default]***

```
    typedef struct foo {
        unsigned char unit[10];
        unsigned int  read_value;
    };

    foo test_value = {

        {"km",      100 },
        {"miles",   50  },
        {0,         20  }
    };
```

Why does this happen?

Answer (score 0):

This solves the problem:

```
    typedef struct foo {
        unsigned char *unit;
        unsigned int  read_value;
    };

    foo test_value = {

        {"km",      100 },
        {"miles",   50  },
        {0,         20  }
    };
```

But if still, someone could explain this better?Please!